# Having trouble getting environment variable into application.conf

Tags: scala, heroku, playframework, redis, playframework-2.0

I'm using Scredis, a scala Redis library. To instantiate a Redis object I have to pass it a config and the path to the config values. (As far as I can tell there is no other way to give the Redis object its hostname and port)

Basically, I need to have the Redis port and host name stored in the config. Now the issue is that I'm trying to use Heroku to deploy this, and the hostname and port both reside in an environment variable. I've learned that I can access env vars from the application.conf, but since they are stored as one long string there's no way for me to break it up before I pass it to the Redis object. I know how to grab the env var from the env var in code, but seeing as I can't pass it directly I'm at a complete loss for how to do this.

Here is the configuration information for Scredis: https://github.com/Livestream/scredis/wiki/Configuration

Using redis-cloud for java/scala on heroku:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rediscloud#using-redis-from-java

Comment: What is this one long string? Can you not set env vars for both `REDIS_HOST` and `REDIS_PORT` in Heroku?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According [these examples](https://github.com/Livestream/scredis/wiki/Client) from `scredis`, it is also possible to create a client placing the configuration in the code.

```
// Creates a non-blocking client with provided parameters, falling back to default
// configuration for non-provided parameters.
val clientWithParameters = Client(
  host = "192.168.1.1",
  port = 6380,
  passwordOpt = Some("foobar")
)
```

So, a pseudo-combination of the two would probably be something like:

```
val redisUri = URI( System.getenv("REDISCLOUD_URL") )
val redisClient =  Client(
    host = redisUri.getHost(),
    port =  redisUri.getPort(),
    passwordOpt = redisUri.getPassword()
)
```

Comment: I knew it was a good idea showing you this question - your answer's way better :)

Answer (score 2):

Typesafe Config and hence Play Framework makes this extremely easy for you since Typesafe Config also loads environment variables to resolve config values. You basically have two options.

**Option 1**: Make sure the environment variables have the same name as the configuration key `scredis` expects. This is useful in cases where you want to change the given config value on startup - for example you have the following `application.conf`:

```
{
  foo = bar
}
```

But at runtime you want the value of `foo` to be `baz`. Then you can either pass the new value through environment variable or `-D`.

```
$ foo=baz activator run
$ activator run -Dfoo=baz
```

**Option 2:** In you `application.conf` have a placeholder to read the environment variable. Assuming the enviroment variables Heroku passes you are `REDIS_HOST` and `REDIS_PORT`, then in your `application.conf` you can do the following:

```
scredis {
  redis {
    host = ${REDIS_HOST}
    port = ${REDIS_PORT}
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer - I am no Scala expert :)

It looks like `scredis` is configured via `application.conf` and the Typesafe Config Library, so one way of doing this is generating the fly on dyno startup.

According to [Heroku's build behavior for Scala](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scala-support#build-behavior), the way to do this is by adding a startup script to the mandatory `stage` task. The startup script should, in your case, parse the contents of the `REDISCLOUD_URL` env var and write them to the `application.conf` file.